# SonarQube portfolio calculation failing

Tags: sonarqube

Since upgrade to SonarQube 7.6 (from 7.4), portfolio background tasks keep failing with following exception. Any ideas how to resolve the problem? Tried to re-scan projects which seemed to work but now it seems like it just changes order of item processing so eventually I got back to the first project that was failing.

```
org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=PortProj,type=PROJECT_VIEW}  located Port(type=VIEW)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50)
    at com.A.B.C.D.B.A.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeStep(ComputationStepExecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:72)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:59)
    at com.A.B.C.D.E.A.A.A(Unknown Source)
    at com.A.B.C.D.E.A.D.A(Unknown Source)
    at com.A.B.C.G.A.B(Unknown Source)
    at com.A.B.C.G.A.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:207)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.run(CeWorkerImpl.java:189)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:156)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$TrackRunningState.get(CeWorkerImpl.java:131)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:83)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: value can not be converted to level because current value type is a NO_VALUE
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.measure.Measure.checkValueType(Measure.java:307)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.measure.Measure.getLevelValue(Measure.java:290)
    at com.A.B.C.D.B.A$_A.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.processLeaf(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:148)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.process(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:125)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.visitProjectView(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:111)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects need to be re-scanned to get rid of the error. It seemed to not work for me but when I eventually removed couple projects that I knew were not re-scanned I got it working fine...